# How to retrieve virtual machines tags from vCenter VMWare using .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, tags, vmware, vcenter

I am trying to retrieve the tags from each of the virtual machines on vCenter for a project I am writing for the company I work for. I succesfully have set up the .NET environment with PowerCLI and I can successfully retrieve all VM with name and such, but when I try to get the tags, I get an empty array.

```
// Connect to VMware SDK service

Client.Connect(address_vmw);

Client.Login(username_vmw, password_vmw);



// Get all Virtual Machines

vmw_machines = Client.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, null, null);



foreach (VirtualMachine machine in vmw_machines) //for each machine in VMW

{

string machineName = machine.Name; // this works fine

dynamic machineTags = machine.Tag; // I need to fix this line!



foreach (dynamic tag in machineTags) // it is an empty array!

{

   Console.Write(tag);

}



...
```

This are the tags I need to retrieve on vCenter:
[Screenshot of vCenter on HTML GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSsgJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tagging operations were moved over to the REST API endpoint starting in vSphere 6.0, so you'll want to take a look at the vSphere Automation SDK for .NET: https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-.net